# League Positions in Gaelic Football

Tags: ranking, gaelic-football

In the Allianz Gaelic Football League tables from Ireland, when two teams are level on match points and also on points difference, how are they separated for the league tables?

I presumed that a team with a superior points total would be placed ahead, or maybe the positions would be decided on the teams' head-to-head results but, looking at some current tables, this does not seem to be the case.

Answer (score 2):

A Tie-breaker is defined as follows, if only two teams are level on league points:

> 1. The team that won the head-to-head match is ranked first
> 2. If this game was a draw, score difference (total scored minus total conceded in all games) is used to rank the teams
> 3. If score difference is identical, total scored is used to rank the teams
> 4. If still identical, a play-off is required
>
> If three or more teams are level on league points, score difference is
>   used to rank the teams.

Reference: [2019_National_Football_League_(Ireland)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2019_National_Football_League_(Ireland))